# How to Prevent the Beautify Extension from Formatting Inline Javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I want the ESLint extension to be the only formatter inside inline Javascript. Beautify just screws it up and I have to correct it manually.

I have added these lines to my .jsbeautifyrc file:

```
    "format.contentUnformatted": "script",
    "format.unformatted": "script",
```

But it has no effect: Beautify still formats every line in the html file. What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/HookyQR/VSCodeBeautify/blob/master/README.md) it should be something like:

```
{
  "unformatted": ["script"]
}
```

If that does not work, then maybe with the `language` setting this might work.

> You can control which file types, extensions, or specific file names should be beautified with the beautify.language setting.
>
> ```
> {
>  "beautify.language": {
>    "js": {
>      "type": ["javascript", "json"],
>      "filename": [".jshintrc", ".jsbeautifyrc"]
>      // "ext": ["js", "json"]
>      // ^^ to set extensions to be beautified using the javascript beautifier
>    },
>    "css": ["css", "scss"],
>    "html": ["htm", "html"]
>    // ^^ providing just an array sets the VS Code file type
>  }
> }
> ```

Above configuration should enable formatting only on specified .js files.

Good luck.